# How do I get started in graphics design side of web design?

Tags: photoshop

In past years I have learned the most important languages for web development (CSS, HTML, JS, PHP) and I can create good-structured sites.

But an important part of web design is the **images** used for buttons, backgrounds, text, gradients... Also the main logo is a very important element in the layout of a website.

However, I dont know how to get started in that side of web design for developing good looking websites.

What tools should use for that purposes? Do you know good guides?

I have read one books and some guides about photoshop, but they are about graphics design in general and I am looking for a guide/books focused on **web** graphic design and also (if posible), focused on **how** to place these images correctly using css and xhtml.

PD: Sorry for the bad English.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm certainly no pro, and probably not even very good myself, but I think one good way is to just do it. The more you practice, the more you learn and improve, and your designs will get better and better.

As you are building sites, you'll run into "problems" which you can then find answers to on the internet or on sites like stack overflow. It's also useful to look at designs from other sites and try to see how they did it.

In terms of tools, you probably don't need anything really fancy to get started. I mostly only use [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) and [InkScape](http://www.inkscape.org/). I try to use few images if I can.

Comment: Litle by litle I am imporoving making designs, your advices are very good. It's true that the images can make the difference but they aren't strictly necessary in web design. I admit I have trouble designing the main logo, but I'll try to make something simple. Thanks.

Comment: If you do work for a company or organization that already has a logo, that makes it easy, of course. But I'm also not good at making original logos. I'm not that good at making images for the site's decoration either, like icons, borders, etc. However, If you do any serious web designing and have trouble with that stuff, you can hire someone with talent to do the images while you take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the web designing tutorials.

- [40+ Greatest Web Interface Design Photoshop Tutorials, Part I](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/40-greatest-web-interface-design-tutorials-photoshop-tutorial/)
- [Pegaweb](http://www.pegaweb.com/)
- [Web dev tuts](http://www.webdevtuts.net/)
- [WebDesign](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/tutorials/page-1.html)
- [25 Photoshop Tutorials for Web Designers](http://sixrevisions.com/photoshop/25-photoshop-tutorials-for-web-designers/)
- [Blue Print Layout: Converting a PSD to HTML Tutorial](http://www.webdevtuts.net/coding/css/blue-print-layout-converting-a-psd-to-html-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

Ever since I started learning web design & development what I find most effective for learning is looking at other web sites. In looking at other web sites it is advisable to look at examples of both good and bad design, just so you're aware of the difference.

Learning by example is, for me, the best way to learn because you really see how design concepts and ideas are applied. When you finally have an idea on the look and feel that you want to apply to your web site then you can start researching on the technicalities of creating them (e.g. Google 'how to paint shop pro web 2.0-style buttons' or 'how to photoshop gradient web buttons'). It's really up to you on which tool you want to use because it depends on what you're comfortable with using. An upside of using Photoshop, I think, is that there are a lot of tutorials that you can just Google for online.

I recommend going to http://www.alistapart.com/ for guides, articles & tutorials on web design.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the boostrap plugin. I have discovered a site http://www.webdesignernews.com/
You may see there are many ideas of creating a website.

[This site](http://tympanus.net) is very useful to create professional style navigation bars and loading style or types of buttons, etc.

For logos and all [Canva](http://www.canva.com) is best to use where you can design logos facebook cover, poster and all necessary things. All the sites mentioned above are completely free. 
For some ideas of creating web pages You may visit [TheSoftwareGuy.](http://thesoftwareguy.in)

Answer (score 0):

believing that knowing how to use photoshop is enough to tell people you can design websites is wrong. Tools can definitely make the difference but that doesn't replace a person's real talent and skill that gives the design a unique edge.

my 2 cents.

Comment: Sorry if my question is annoying for you. I am just interested in web developing as a **hobby** and *not* for being able to tell people I can design websites.

Comment: i think you misinterpreted my answer.

my point is, web design doesn't necessarily have to rely with the popular tools. It's your imagination and ability to know what best techniques to use that will give the edge.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand what you meant, but you are right. Actually I am new a web design and I don't know the best techniques to make a good-locking web design, but I am improving with each new design I make (I am on my third website). I hope I could make profesional designs some day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approch like create a template using Photoshop or Gimph. If you are creating a site for client create a 2-3 templates with different layouts and show them to client. If they are good and approved, create a HTML templates for those and after that embed server side.

After a practice can design a better site.